# How to write to log file with Python-API in caffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I have a python script to do my training with caffe. My `start_train.py` looks like this:

```
python train.py 2>&1 | tee $LOGGING
```

and in my `train.py` I have code like this:

sys.stderr.write("[%s] Iteration %d: %f seconds" % (time.strftime("%c"), it, time.time()-start))

However, this code is not written to the `$LOGGING` file. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-u` to your command like this:

```
python -u train.py 2>&1 | tee $LOGGING
```

and use

```
print("[%s] Iteration %d: %f seconds" % (time.strftime("%c"), it, time.time()-start)
```